# How to create a Protocol in a Package without requiring Variables to be implemented Public?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

**Context**

I have a `Protocol`, let's name it `Entity`, defined in a `Swift Package`. Since I want to use it in my projects, I set the `Access Level` to `Public`. However, `Xcode` is forcing me to set all `Variables` and `Methods` to `Public` as well, that were specified in the `Protocol`.

> **Compiler Error:** Property 'name' must be declared public because it matches a requirement in public protocol 'Entity'

---

**Code**

```swift
// Swift Package
public protocol Entity {
    static var name: String
}

// Project
extension SomeEntity: Entity { // Compiler Error
    static var name: String = "Some Entity"
}
```

---

**Question**

- How can I declare a `Protocol` in a `Swift Package` without requiring all `Requirements` to be made `Public` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that.

If you make a type conform to a protocol, the conform will have the same access identifiers as the type itself. So if you make a `public` type conform to a protocol, the protocol conformance will be `public` as well.

In order for a type to conform to a protocol, all protocol requirements must be met. And if you are able to refer to a type as the protocol it conforms to, you must be able to access all protocol requirements as well.
So if you declare a type `public` and make it conform to a protocol, you must declare all protocol requirements (both properties and methods) as `public`.

This is by design and you cannot get around it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! However, let's take the `SwiftUI View Protocol` as an example: Since it is defined in another `Package`, it must be `Public`, but you do not habe to make the required `var body` `Public` when adopting it. How is that possible?

Comment: @christophriepe if your `View` is `public`, you must make `body` `public` as well. As I've said, the protocol requirements must have at least the same accessibility specifier as the type itself - so if your view is `private` or `internal`, its `body` does not have to be `public`.